# How to inject WeakReference Fragment using Koin - Android

Tags: android, weak-references, koin

I have a class that relies on `WeakReference<Fragment>`.

```
class ExampleManager(reference: WeakReference<Fragment>)
```

How would I inject `ExampleManager` constructor?

```
val exampleModule = module {
   factory { ExampleManager(get()) }
}

private val exmpManager: ExampleManager by inject()
```

At the end I receive error:

> No definition found for class:'java.lang.ref.WeakReference'. Check your definitions!

How can I implement definition for `WeakReference<Fragment>` in my case?

Comment: Did you import WeakReference package?

Comment: @haruk1515 If you mean import for the class, then yes, otherwise, I could not compile code. Or you meant something else? I'm confused

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to inject a WeakReference using Koin, you can create a factory function that creates the WeakReference and use it in your Koin module definition.

Here's an example:

```
// Factory function to create WeakReference<Fragment>
fun createWeakRef(fragment: Fragment) = WeakReference(fragment)

// Koin module definition
val exampleModule = module {
    factory { (fragment: Fragment) -> ExampleManager(createWeakRef(fragment)) }
}
```

Then, you can use the by inject() delegate to inject the ExampleManager class in your activity or fragment:

```
class ExampleFragment : Fragment() {

    private val exmpManager: ExampleManager by inject { parametersOf(this) }
    // ...
}
```

Here, parametersOf(this) is used to pass the current fragment instance to the factory function.

It is important to mention that, WeakReference is a java class and you should import it using import java.lang.ref.WeakReference

Make sure you have included the created module in your Koin's startKoin function

i recommend to use'lazy' when you are injecting instances that are only used in certain conditions, this can help to avoid unnecessary instantiation and memory leaks.

```
private val exmpManager: ExampleManager by inject { parametersOf(this) }.lazy
```

This way, exmpManager will be instantiated only when it is accessed for the first time.